# Open app from Facebook link

Tags: android, facebook

I'm developing an app that shares some information in facebook. For that I do this:

```
if (FacebookDialog.canPresentShareDialog(getApplicationContext(), 
            FacebookDialog.ShareDialogFeature.SHARE_DIALOG)) {
    // Publish the post using the Share Dialog
        FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(this)
        .setName(attraction.getName())
        .setLink("http://developer.neosperience.com/")   
        .setDescription(attraction.getDescription())
        .setRef(String.valueOf(id_attraction))
        .setPicture(pictureURLtoShare)
        .build();
        uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
    }
```

My problem is I need to send a parameter (id_attraction), so when the post from facebook is clicked it will open my app and I receive that parameter. I thought that setRef would work but I receive null.
This is how I receive the Intent:

```
AppLinkData appLinkData = AppLinkData.createFromActivity(this);
if (appLinkData != null) {
    Bundle arguments = appLinkData.getArgumentBundle();
    //appLinkData.
    if (arguments != null) {
        String targetUrl = arguments.getString("target_url");
        if (targetUrl != null) {
          Log.i("Activity FB", "Target URL: " + targetUrl);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know if it's the correct way to do this but I found a workaround. I send the parameter attached to the url using '?' so everything on the right of ? will be ignored by the browser.

```
if (FacebookDialog.canPresentShareDialog(getApplicationContext(), 
            FacebookDialog.ShareDialogFeature.SHARE_DIALOG)) {
    // Publish the post using the Share Dialog
        FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(this)
        .setName(attraction.getName())
        .setLink("http://developer.neosperience.com/?"+id_attraction)   
        .setDescription(attraction.getDescription())
        .setPicture(pictureURLtoShare)
        .build();
        uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
    }
```

and then I receive it like this:

```
AppLinkData appLinkData = AppLinkData.createFromActivity(this);
if (appLinkData != null) {
    Bundle arguments = appLinkData.getArgumentBundle();
    //appLinkData.
    if (arguments != null) {
        String targetUrl = arguments.getString("target_url");
        if (targetUrl != null) {
          String[] partOfUrl = targetUrl.split("\\?");
          id_attraction = partOfUrl[1];
          Log.i("Activity FB", "Target URL: " + targetUrl);
        }
    }
```

}